# Can you create JavaScript like objects in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

As the question states, I am learning C# and I am wondering if it is possible to have a globally available object that behaves like objects in javascript?

Meaning, it should have something like the following features:

1. Can have some public properties with default values (preferably of any type, but at minimum strings)
2. Can be imported and be globally available in another module
3. Default properties can be accessed from another module (and edited, if possible, but not necessary)
4. New properties can be set from another module

Now unfortunately I don't really know how to approach this task. I know that getting and updating properties requires defining "setters" and "getters", which is fine for the default ones, but how do I create new ones dynamically, from another module?

Is it possible to assign arbitrary types to this new property, without defining the type in the setter?
I know that dictionaries can be used in C#, but i still have to specify the type, and I dont know how to make them behave like global classes, instead of having to pass them as attributes, if I want to use my dictionary inside a different class

As a simplified example, in javascript we can do the following:

**somecomponent.js:**

```js
export default {
    prop1: "somevalue",
    prop2: null,
}
```

**mainfile.js:**

```js
import myComponent from './somecomponent.js'

console.log(myComponent.prop1) // will output "somevalue"

myComponent.prop2 = True // will set the value of prop2 to True, from null

myComponent.newProp = {} // will create a new property that did not exist before, and assign an object to it
```

Now, obviously C# will have a different syntax, but is it possible to have something that will be functionally similar?

Comment: You can't. C# and JavaScript are different languages that solve different problems, consequently they have very different type-systems and approaches to data-modelling.

Comment: You can leverage `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject`, but it's probably best to think of a solution that fits C# better rather than try and implement JavaScript idioms

Comment: @Matthew `dynamic` isn't type-safe, and `ExpandoObject` is an implementation of `dynamic`. I'm not a fan of `dynamic` at all because it defeats the point of using a strongly-typed language in the first place.

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies...

Comment: Just because you can in JavaScript doesn't mean you should. Try and stay away from global variables in JS.

Comment: I completely agree @Dai, but this is the closest thing to JavaScript behaviour, whether that's a good thing is up for OP to decide.

Comment: What do you mean by "default properties"? Members of `export default` are not called "default properties".

Comment: @Dai I meant default values for some properties, that are set (or even hardcoded) when defining the object, and are available (the values can be retrieved) when it is imported somewhere else

Comment: @PetruTanas C# does not work like that _at all_ though. But first, let me ask you: how well do you understand the differences between structurally-typed, prototype-based OOP and nominatively-typed, `class`-based, single-inheritance-based OOP? And do you understand the difference between a `class`  an an `object` (in both JS and C#)?

Comment: @Steve You cannot inherit from objects in C# (as objects are values, not types) - so I'm not sure what you're proposing there...

Comment: @Dai That is the purpose of this question. "not possible and this is why" would be a perfectly acceptable answer. But an important note is that performance, or safety, is not necessary relevant for me at this point. I am interested to know if it is possible in principle, and, of course, if it is, but there are reasons as to why it absolutely should not be done, then I would like to know them as well

Comment: @PetruTanas I'm half-way through writing an answer which explains why.

Comment: @PetruTanas Also, what do you mean by "instead of having to pass them as attributes"? Do you mean _pass them as arguments_ (for method parameters)? Because an Attribute in C# is something completely different, and "Attributes" isn't a term used in JavaScript's type-system either.

Comment: @Dai I was referring to in/out parameters, I might made gotten the terminology wrong, but, if I understand correctly, if I want to pass an object to a method of a class, to be used inside that method, I have to define the 'in' value, as the type of the class the object belongs to. As far as I understand, if I define an object in main, it is not available globally (please correct me if this is wrong)

Comment: @PetruTanas That is incorrect (and you really need to stop using the terms "value", "class", and "object" interchangeably, they are all distinct concepts and it confuses my attempts to infer what you're really after.

Comment: @Dai maybe an example would be more helpful to explain what I mean: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XKEmid

Comment: @PetruTanas That example you wrote (using shared objects in a higher scope) is very bad  programming practice, regardless of language (it's just as bad in JavaScript as it is bad in C#): globals represent _shared state_, and mutable shared state is bad, _bad_, **bad** because it's not thread-safe and almost impossible to reason about the parent object's state lifetime. In both JavaScript and C#: If a function/method needs data then it **must** be passed as a function/method parameter argument or be an instance field of the current `this` object.

Comment: @Dai You are right, that is, of course, true. But right now I am trying to understand the functional similarities and differences between these languages, and performance, thread safety, best practices, etc is not really relevant. As this setup will work in javaScript, I want to know why it will not work in c#. And if there is a functionally identical setup that will work in this manner, I would of course want to know the problems with it.

Comment: @PetruTanas Please see my answer below.

Comment: @PetruTanas I think you clicked Accept before fully reading my answer... that's presumptuous of you.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for answering. I did read it, and went on to test the code examples. I dont really see the point of this comment, you dont want it accepted? :D

Comment: @PetruTanas Of course I like to see my posts marked as Accepted, but only when it's done for the right reasons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you create JavaScript like objects in C#

**You can't**. C# and JavaScript are different languages that solve different problems, consequently they have very different type-systems and approaches to data-modelling.

I've made this table which I hope indicates the fundamental differences between C# and JavaScript's type-systems. In particular, I want to draw your attention towards the important and fundamental differences in what "Properties" are and what `object` means.

|  | C# | JavaScript |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Product types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type) | `class` or `struct` | `object` instances |
| Type extension paradigm | Single-inheritance (type inheritance) | Prototype inheritance (value inheritance) |
| `Object foo =` / `object foo =` is... | An arbitrary reference to a nominatively-typed GC heap-allocated defined region in memory (including boxed values). | A hashtable instance. |
| Properties are... | Statically-defined getter/setter methods with-or-without backing fields. | Hashtable entries with `string` keys and arbitrary values (including scalars, objects (other hashtables), and functions) |
| `class` is... | A statically-defined type in its entirety. | Shorthand for a constructor function. |
| Type identity | Statically defined. Type-identity is strictly nominative. | (Generally) runtime-defined. Weak structural-typing. Type-identity is nominative when using constructor functions correctly (e.g. `instanceof`). TypeScript introduces strict structural typing. |
| Undefined type name | Compiler error | Runtime error. |
| Undefined type member dereference | Compiler error | Runtime error. |

---

> I am wondering if it is possible to have a globally available object that behaves like objects in javascript?

- C# doesn't have globals.

  - In C#, every value and method (function) must exist within a *type* definition (e.g. `class`, `struct`, `interface`, etc).
- I suppose the closest equivalent is a value exposed via a `public static` field or property, but unless the value's type is immutable you should not be manipulating it from C# program code because of thread-safety and concurrency issues. JavaScript doesn't have this problem because JavaScript is strictly single-threaded and does not allow for concurrent access to shared resources.

> Can have some public properties with default values (preferably of any type, but at minimum strings)

You can define a type (i.e. a `class`) in C# with properties that have default values that can be overwritten by explicit values passed into the class's constructor. But you will still need to specify exact types for those properties.

If you want an arbitrary collection of values with named entries then use a `Dictionary<K,V>` instead. As `Dictionary<K,V>` is strongly-typed you'll need to use either `V: Object` (ewwwww) or define a custom union `struct` that explicitly and exhaustively covers all possible JavaScript-like values *and* `Func` and `Action` delegate-types for function-properties if you so wish.

> Can be imported and be globally available in another module

- C# doesn't have "imports" or "modules".
- In C#, any `public` or `internal` type in any `.cs` file can be used by any other `.cs` file in the same project.

  - Though `internal` types cannot be used by any other project.
  - And you may need to add a `using YourProject.ChildNamespace` to consuming files.

> Default properties can be accessed from another module (and edited, if possible, but not necessary)

I'm unsure what you mean here, because "default properties" simply *is not a thing* in JavaScript nor C#.

> I know that getting and updating properties requires defining "setters" and "getters", which is fine for the default ones, but how do I create new ones dynamically, from another module?

Again, "default" is not a meaningful term in this context in either language.

And C# is a strictly-typed, statically-typed language: you cannot add or remove members to types at runtime (at least as far as this conversation is concerned).

Remember that a JavaScript `object` is really just a view of a hashtable, so it sounds to me like you just need a `Dictionary<K,V>`, or even `ExpandoObject` (as @Matthew suggests) as your post implies that you don't want to take advantage of type-safety at all.

> Is it possible to assign arbitrary types to this new property, without defining the type in the setter?

Not at runtime. Only statically (i.e. in a defined `class` which is compiled once at design-time). Note that the `dynamic` type in C# is *really* just an `ExpandoObject` behind-the-scenes, which is just another kind of dictionary/map/hashtable, just like JavaScript's `object` type.

> I know that dictionaries can be used in C#, but i still have to specify the type

While you *do-indeed have-to* specify the `TValue` type when using `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, it shouldn't be a blocking problem though, as you can use any of the following types for `TValue`:

- Use `Object?` (or `Object` if you're targeting .NET Framework 4.x) for `TValue`, but this is not type-safe and introduces too many awkward consequences for me to seriously consider.
- Using `dynamic` (for `TValue`) has the same issues as using `Object`.
- Using `dynamic` (instead of a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` entirely) is, just, *no*.
- Using a type-union ([tip: use `OneOf<>`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OneOf/)) to define the exhaustive set of valid types. This can also be recursive.

---

Below is my first personal interpretation of your JavaScript example, using only statically defined and immutable types (as thread-safety is largely impossible without immutable data):

**MyValues.cs:**

```cs
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyValues
    {
        public String   Prop1 { get; init; } = "somevalue";
        public Boolean? Prop2 { get; init; } = null;
    }

    public class MyDerived : MyValues
    {
        public SomeOtherType NewProp { get; init; }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```cs
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            MyValues myValues1 = new MyValues()
            {
                Prop2 = false
            };

            Console.WriteLine( "Prop1: \"{0}\".", myValues1.Prop1 ); // "Prop1: "somevalue"."
            Console.WriteLine( "Prop2: {0}.", myValues1.Prop2 ); // "Prop2: True."

            //

            MyDerived myValues2 = new MyDerived()
            {
                Prop1 = "newStringValue",
                Prop2 = true,
                NewProp = new SomeOtherType()
            };
        
            Console.WriteLine( "Prop1: \"{0}\".", myValues2.Prop1 ); // "Prop1: "newStringValue"."
            Console.WriteLine( "Prop2: {0}.", myValues2.Prop2 ); // "Prop2: True."
        }
    }
}
```

Note that:

- The `Prop1` and `Prop2` properties in `class MyValues` above wrap corresponding hidden private instance fields generated by the compiler. Prior to C# 3.0 every property declaration had to have an explicit backing field.
- `MyDerived` inherits from `MyValues` (so it gains `Prop1` and `Prop2` implicitly), however this is just for demonstration purposes: in C# you should not use inheritance as a poor substitute for mixins and member-sharing. Only use inheritance when you're meaningfully implementing an "is" relationship and not a "has" relationship.

  - Unfortunately even C# 10.0 (released in November 2021) still doesn't have true mixins and similarly its support for object-composition is very weak (let alone any kind of true algebratic types (ADTs)). While C# 11 will likely have simpler ADTs I'm not expecting support for true unions, products, and intersection-types until after C# 12 or even 13.
- Since C# 9.0, properties can be declared with `init`-setters, which indicates that the property can only be set inside a constructor or inside an object-initializer. My example is using `init`-setters for simplicity, but they should be avoided in production-code *except* for truly optional values and *never* for any required values because the constructor cannot provide guarantees about object-initializers, as object-initializers run after the constructor has returned.

---

Below is my second personal interpretation of your JavaScript example, using dictionary collection-types with a `OneOf<...>` union to add type-safety.

**Warning:** I've been having issues getting `global using` to work in C# 10.0, especially with self-referential type-aliases. While my code below doesn't compile, it is still possible to convert type-aliases to `struct` wrappers that achieve the same effect.

**Utility.cs:**

```cs
namespace MyProject
{
    // "Global Usings" imbue a type-alias with project-wide visibility, but requires C# 10.0.
    // Also, this doesn't compile for me, but *in-principle* the code below is still correct.

    global using ValueDict = Dictionary<String,PossibleValueTypes>;
    global using PossibleValueTypes = OneOf<ValueDict,String,Int32,Boolean,Decimal,Null>;

    global using ImmutablePossibleValueTypes = OneOf<ImmutableValueDict,String,Int32,Boolean,Decimal>;
    global using ImmutableValueDict = ImmutableDictionary<String,PossibleValueTypes,Null>;

    // This empty struct is used as a type-tag to allow `null` (which is a reference-value in C#/.NET) to be used _almost_ like a type (just like in TypeScript, where `null` is both a type and a value).
    // But as C# is not JavaScript you really shouldn't ever do this (as C# has (almost) first-class support for nullable reference types already).
    public struct Null {}
}
```

**MyValues.cs:**

```cs
using System;
using OneOf;

namespace MyProject
{
    public static class MyValues
    {
        public static ImmutableValueDict Values { get; } = new ImmutableValueDict()
        {
            { "Prop1", "someValue" },
            { "Prop2", new Null() },
        };
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```cs
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            ImmutableValueDict myValues1 = MyValues.Values;

            Console.WriteLine( "Prop1: \"{0}\".", myValues1.Prop1 ); // "Prop1: "somevalue"."
            Console.WriteLine( "Prop2: {0}.", myValues1.Prop2 ); // "Prop2: MyProject.Null"

            //

            ImmutableValueDict myValues2 = new ImmutableValueDict( myValues1 ) // <-- This constructor overload will copy the entries in `myValues1` into `myValues2` - though as `myValues2`'s collection-initializer overwrites both Prop1 and Prop2 it's kinda moot.
            {
                { "Prop1", "newStringValue" ),
                { "Prop2", true ),
                { "NewProp", new ImmutableValueDict() ) // Nested dicts!
            };
        
            Console.WriteLine( "Prop1: \"{0}\".", myValues2.Prop1 ); // "Prop1: "newStringValue"."
            Console.WriteLine( "Prop2: {0}.", myValues2.Prop2 ); // "Prop2: True."
        }
    }
}
```